# python conditional one or the other but not both and print the True one

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to make an if statement to check two variables if they're > 10
if both of them are True, I want the code to pass or stop. But if one of them is True, I want the code to print that one True variable.

For example:

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 11

if (var1 >= 10) is not (var2 >= 10):
    # print the true variable
else:
    pass
```

In this case, I want it to print:

```
var2 = 11
```

but if `var1` is the True variable, I want it to print `var1` instead. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: a single `if` statement can't determine what "caused it to be True" (trying to speak intuitively here...), but you can try using multiple  `if`s to check exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For a more flexible solution (a larger number of vars), one could do something along the lines of:

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 11

num = [var for var in [var1, var2] if var >= 10]
if len(num) > 1:
  pass
if len(num) == 1:
  print(num[0])
else:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 11

if (var1 > 10 and var2 > 10) or (var1 < 10 and var2 < 10):  # checks if both vars are greater or lesser than 10.
    pass
else:  # if one of them only is greater than 10 it is printed
    if var1 > 10:
        print('var1: %d' % var1)
    if var2 > 10:
        print('var2: %d' % var2)
```

Comment: What you are doing in your first if, is the xor operator, it could be simplified by this `(var1 > 10) ^ (var2 > 10)`

Comment: @Davichete Correct!

Comment: Please add some explanation what it does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: No matter how simple it is, code-only answers generally appear in the review queues and may be subject of a deletion vote. I just tell :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the xor operator in python, since simplifies code and avoid unnecessary conditionals:

```py
if (var1 > 10) ^ (var2 > 10):

    if var1 > 10:
        print(var1)

    elif var2 > 10:
        print(var2)
```

*EDIT:* It could be simplified even more:

```py
if (var1 > 10) ^ (var2 > 10):

    print(var1 if var1 > 10 else var2)
```

see [xor operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) or [xor operator python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)

(PD: Another alternative is using `!=`)